# How to use apostrophe (') within SQL query in R dbSendQuery command?

Tags: r, postgresql

I connected my postgre database to R. It works fine but when I need to use an apostrophe in my SQL query R gives an error "Unexpected Symbol".

```
 DATE_PART('EPOCH', AGE(created_at,submitted_at))
```

whole part in R

```
ev_duration <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SELECT

                       name,

                      ROUND(CAST(DATE_PART('EPOCH', AGE(created_at,submitted_at)) AS NUMERIC) / (60*60),2) as evaluation_duration
                       FROM  submissions
                       ;')
```

I searched but could not find the right solution. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: I haven't had time to play with this, but `DBI` now has a `sqlInterpolate` function that could be useful here and provides security against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape it with a backslash.

```
ev_duration <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SELECT
                       name,

                      ROUND(CAST(DATE_PART(\'EPOCH\', AGE(created_at,submitted_at)) AS NUMERIC) / (60*60),2) as evaluation_duration
                       FROM  submissions
                       ;')
```